# Do search engines see pages with #? and without #? as separate pages?

Tags: url, seo

Let's say I have following links:

1. `http://www.example.com/catalog/view/123/`
2. `http://www.example.com/catalog/view/123/#?param1=10&param2=20`
3. `http://www.example.com/catalog/view/123/#?param4=40&param2=100`

Everything after `#?` is generated by JavaScript, so all links point to the same page.

Do search engines see those pages?

When someone shares those links via social networks, do search engines distinct those links or see them as one page?

P.S. I know about `#!` or `_escaped_fragment`. It is not this case.

Comment: Click on the SEO tag.  Read the top.

Answer (score 0):

No. They are not considered separate urls. If you want to absolutely sure add canonical url to every page. That way you would be able to tell Google what is the actually url of the page.